# Wall follower in 3D maze

Tags: algorithms

How should I apply, let's say,  `left-hand rule` when I hit a wall and both up and right is free to go? If I always choose up, I might be trapped in an up and down loop while right is the exit. Same happens when I always choose right.

Comment: If "left-hand rule" and "Wall follower" means what I think it does, then you run the risk of getting stuck in a 2D maze, if your maze has a wall that doesn't connect to the outer boundary.

Comment: @TheoBendit Let's assume there are no disjointed parts :)